# How to modify elements inside List using stream and ignore last element?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following list:

```
var list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
```

I want to achieve something like that:

```
// "a, "
// "b, "
// "c"
```

So I did that:

```
var formattedList = list.stream()
        .map(el -> el + ", ")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is working almost fine:

```
// "a, "
// "b, "
// "c, "
```

but as you can see I don't know how to "ommit" last element in my stream.

Could someone help me achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.join()`

```java
var list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
String.join(",", list) // returns a,b,c
```

I assumed you wanted to join the elements. But if you don't, I think stream api is not suitable for this. Traditional iterator would work better. Because your requirement is based on index of the element. In streams, index information is not provided.

Comment: true... streams are not great idea there, thanks

Comment: @taha There is a collector with joining for streams as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/70079503/1261166

Answer (score 3):

Tahas answer is great if you have a list, but if you for some use case have a stream you can just just do.

```
String result = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.limit()` to limit the elements of the original list that are streamed:

```
        Stream.concat(
                list.stream().map(el -> el + ", ").limit(list.size() - 1),
                Stream.of(list.get(list.size() - 1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I re-read the post and it seems OP actually wants to apply the mapping to all but the last element, but the resulting list should still have all of the element. Or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep last element

Comment: This doesn't keep the last element (and my answer didn't either, that's why I deleted it)

Comment: Ah, well that's true... It doesn't actually keep last element.

Comment: Good point, @FedericoklezCulloca. I have updated my answer to achieve the intended result while still using streams, although I think Taha's answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

Could be done with an `IntStream`.

```
var list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

var formattedList = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> i != list.size() - 1 ? list.get(i) + ", " : list.get(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, if you do need a string and not a list of objects, of course it would be more rational to use `String#join` as suggested.